# how can i output a Linux command in python popen

Tags: python

Write a python program that uses the popen function to obtain the output found by executing the ls -l command. After that find out the number of directories and the number of files after executing the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 0):

You could use os.listdir()

```
import os
dirs = os.listdir()
print(len(dirs))
```

if you want to filter out all the directories, you could use this

```
for x in dirs:
    if not os.path.isdir():
        dirs.remove(x)
```

Of course, popen could work as well, but I think it is way easier to do it like this.

To change the current directory you can use

```
os.chdir()
```

and to display the current directory use

```
os.getcwd()
```